# How to customize an icon and icon background color using a toaster from react tostify?

Tags: reactjs

I have this onSubmit that when the response is successful render a toaster. But I cannot see a way to customize the toaster as showed in the image here below:

```
  [![const onSubmit: FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = async (event: any) => {
    try {
      if (!organisationId) {
        throw Error('\[userDetailsEdit\] - organisationId is not present');
      }

      await handleSubmit(async (formData) => {
        await updateUserData({
          data: { ...formData, id: data.id },
          organisationId
        }).unwrap();
       onSuccess && onSuccess();
       toast.success("Invitation has been sent to the user's email updated", {
        position: 'bottom-right',
        autoClose: 5000,
        hideProgressBar: true,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: true
      });
      })(event);
    } catch (error: any) {
      setTimeout(
        () =>
          setFormErrors({
            error,
            setError,
            fields: Object.keys(schema.fields)
          }),
        50
      );
    }
  };][1]][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### React Toastify. Custom icons

To unify icons and not to pass it for each of toast() instance we can do following (code below).
In combination with https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/how-to-style/ , we can achieve pretty flexible and robust solution that has all defaults in the container. We do not need to modify hardly each toast() instance.

```
interface ToastContainerWrapperProps {
  toastContainerProps?: ToastContainerProps;
}

const ToastContainerWrapper: FunctionComponent<ToastContainerWrapperProps> = ({ toastContainerProps }) => {
  const getIcon = (type: string): React.ReactComponentElement<any> | undefined => {
    switch (type) {
      case 'success':
        return <SuccessIcon />;
      case 'error':
        return <ErrorIcon />;
      case 'warning':
        return <WarningIcon />;
      case 'info':
        return <InfoIcon />;
      default:
        return undefined;
    }
  };

  return <ToastContainer {...toastContainerProps} icon={({ type }) => getIcon(type)} />;
};

// Set default props for ToastContainerWrapper
ToastContainerWrapper.defaultProps = {
  toastContainerProps: {
    position: 'bottom-right',
    autoClose: 5000,
    hideProgressBar: false,
    newestOnTop: true,
    closeOnClick: false,
    rtl: false,
    pauseOnFocusLoss: true,
    draggable: true,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    transition: Slide,
    closeButton: <ToastifyCloseButton />,
  },
};

export default ToastContainerWrapper;
```

And usage (please notice, that we made a custom component for content of toast message and passed there some of it's attributes):

```
const notify = () =>
    toast((props) => {
      const variation = props.toastProps.type;

      return (
        <ToastifyContent variation={variation} title="Some title" action={() => alert('Click')}>
          <b>I'm bold</b>. :)
        </ToastifyContent>
      );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the codebase I'm working on we customised it by accessing its classes.

Here is what it looks like with the styled-component lib.

```
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify'
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const CustomNotification = styled(ToastContainer)`
  .Toastify__toast {
    ...
  }
  .Toastify__toast--error {
    background-color: ...;
  }
  .Toastify__toast--warning {
    background-color: ...;
  }
  .Toastify__toast--success {
    background-color: ...;
  }
  .Toastify__toast-body {
    ...;
  }
  .Toastify__close-button {
    ...;
  }
`
```

The doc has more info:
https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/how-to-style/

And has a specific page about icons:
https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/icons

```
// With a string
toast.success("You can provide any string", {
  icon: ""
});

// custom icons have access to the theme and the toast type
toast.success("And of course a component of your choice", {
  icon: MyIcon
});

toast.success("Even a function, given you return something that can be rendered", {
  icon: ({theme, type}) =>  <img src="url"/>
});
```